# Is ASE mature enough to start developing android apps?

Tags: android, scripting, ase

I've been checking out the Android Scripting Environment, it looks rather promising. But is it a viable option to make a marketable app in? It seems like the customer would have to download ASE and then run the script from the environment itself.

Comment: Please note that the project is now called Scripting Layer for Android. You may have better luck asking specific questions (rather than unanswerable ones like "is it a viable option") on the SL4A Google Group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the lack of responses, I'm posting this more as a bump and discussion opener than a complete answer. My take is that **SL4A might be good enough for small scripts, but not yet for full blown apps to update to the market**. Just browsing the last couple of months of the discussion group page ([link here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-scripting/topics)), it seems that the API is still changing quite actively. I'm posting some examples below:

- [Issue 514 in android-scripting: Enhanced WebView API](http://groups.google.com/group/android-scripting/browse_thread/thread/5a4c06beb5f0fbea/9b53e0fddf2799e0?lnk=gst&q=change+api#9b53e0fddf2799e0)
- [New unofficial release](http://groups.google.com/group/android-scripting/browse_thread/thread/b70347ced5e7027e#)
- [API Updates](http://groups.google.com/group/android-scripting/browse_thread/thread/bc86d7ce4973bb9b#)
- [Scripts as APKs](http://groups.google.com/group/android-scripting/browse_thread/thread/3faf8061c01eb0e4#)
- [API Browser Changes](http://groups.google.com/group/android-scripting/browse_thread/thread/1d1d6ee7ae638ab8#)

If you have a great script that you want to quickly port to SL4A, give it a shot. But I would not replace java with SL4A at least until it gets an official release.